# Upgrade issue moving from 5.49+ to 5.50*

Tags: civimail, upgrade, database

In moving from 5.49 to 5.50 we seem to lose a table.  All civimails generate a "DB missing table error" and the logs show the following.  We get this error with all of the new versions of 50+ but not the last version of 49.

> Jul 29 10:45:54  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
> (
> [callback] => Array
> (
> [0] => CRM_Core_Error
> [1] => exceptionHandler
> )
>
> [code] => -18
> [message] => DB Error: no such table
> [mode] => 16
> [debug_info] => SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`name` AS `name`, `a`.`label` AS `label`, `a`.`description` AS `description`, `a`$
> FROM civicrm_search_segment a
> ORDER BY `label` ASC
> [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civicrm.civicrm_search_segment' doesn't exist]
> [type] => DB_Error
> [user_info] => SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`name` AS `name`, `a`.`label` AS `label`, `a`.`description` AS `description`, `a`.$
> FROM civicrm_search_segment a
> ORDER BY `label` ASC
> [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civicrm.civicrm_search_segment' doesn't exist]
> [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler p$
> FROM civicrm_search_segment a
> ORDER BY `label` ASC
> [nativecode=1146 ** Table 'civicrm.civicrm_search_segment' doesn't exist]"]

Comment: I've literally just upgraded a site from 5.49 to 5.51.1 and the table called civicrm_search_segment is there post-upgrade. I'm assuming your database is called 'civicrm'? If not that might be the issue

Comment: Also have you run extension upgrades? If you can't get into the UI to the system status page then can do on command line `cv ext:upgrade-db`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks.  The problem seems to have come from not running the extension upgrade at /civicrm/admin/extensions/upgrade?reset=1

After doing that civicrm_search_segment is back.